# Can we update properties of user which has source of authority as Windows Server AD in azure active directory?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Users in azure active directory has source of authority option. It contains either azure active directory or Windows Server AD. So users which has source of authority Windows Server AD they are not updating their fields. Please clear my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot update attributes for on premise users synced using azure ad connect in azure ad. You need to edit attributes in the local ad.

Comment: I am newbie in Azure active directory. You are right but what does this mean edit attributes in the local ad? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: if a user has a source of windows server ad, it means that user exists in an On Premise Active Directory. that was synced to azure via Azure AD Connect. so if you need to change the user's "fields" (attributes) you have to do so on the on-premise active directory servers.